# Is there such a thing as an antisymmetric monoidal category?

Tags: monoidal-categories

I’m slogging my way through “Categories for Quantum Theory, An Introduction”, Chris Heunen and Jamie Vicary, Cambridge University Press. Section 1.2.2 introduces Monoidal Categories to model bipartate processes operating in parallel. If I imagine two Boson particles, which are symmetric under interchange, as the processes, then Symmetric Monoidal Categories look like the go to structure. But Fermions are antisymmetric under interchange, so is there an Antisymmetric Monoidal Category to use for them? Thanks.